# Can't make Windows 7 computer wake up from sleep on schedule

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I am currently trying to automatically wake up my PC early in the morning after I put it to sleep at night. I have created a task via Windows task scheduler (enabling it to wake up the PC) but it's not working at all and I have to wake up the PC manually and it's not even showing up as a wake timer.

[Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpdXO.jpg)

In the above album are my task settings and current power plan's wake timers settings. Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Do you put the computer in Standby or Hibernate at night?

Comment: @Steven: I put the computer to sleep via http://i.imgur.com/goRttNq.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "Allow wake timers" setting in Power Options.

Control Panel, Power Options, Change plan setting (for enabled plan), Change advanced power settings, Sleep, Allow wake timers: Enable

Comment: Wake timers are already enabled when the computer is connected to AC. These are my power plan's current settings: http://i.imgur.com/wtWLg9b.jpg